# htaccess using Multiple Conditions for RewriteRule with multiple REQUEST_URI

Tags: .htaccess

**Only for specifics ip's:**

1. I use .htaccess to send all URL to /
2. I want to add another RewriteCone to move from "test.txt" to "some.php"

htaccess file :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^45\.96\.33\.55$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(test\.txt|some\.php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^45\.96\.33\.55$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/test.txt
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /some.php [L,R=301]
```

My rules ok ?

**update**

I can add more ip's to rules like this ?

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^45\.96\.33\.55$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^33\.33\.55\.66$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(test\.txt|some\.php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^45\.96\.33\.55$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^33\.33\.55\.66$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/test.txt
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /some.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: **Note:** Do not test your rewriterules with `R=301`. This is a permanent redirect, and the browser will cache incorrect attempts for this redirect and will skip your testing url after the first attempt. Change it to the `R` flag (without a number), which is a temporary redirect untill all redirects do what you want! You need to clear your cache too.

Comment: What does work and what doesn't work?

Comment: The problem with update 2 is that you mix up string literals and regex expressions btw.

Comment: The answer is already in your question. That is if you understand everything that is in the rules.

Comment: You say there is a problem in "update 2", and what if i want to add more ip's ?

Comment: You constantly edit your question, and therefore the comment now refers to [a previous version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18930161/5). You've already used the technique you need to use for the question at the bottom of [the current revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18930161/7) and I see no reason why you can't use it again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37779/discussion-between-sumurai8-and-motioz)